# One connection per request? What is the proper way to use SQLAlchemy connections in a web application?

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I'm creating a web application that uses [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) to connect to a MySQL database. This may be a newbie question, but when is the proper time to call `Engine.connect()`? Should I be:

1. Calling `Engine.connect()` every time a web request is made, and closing the connection once the request is processed? **OR**
2. Calling `Engine.connect()` several times in the very beginning of my application to create several connections. Then every time I process a request, I use one of the connections, and never close them?

I'm also not exactly sure I understand the concept of a **Connection Pool** in general. Does the connection pool maintain a series of open connections to the database, and then hand a connection off whenever `Engine.connect()` is called? Or, does the pool establish a new connection every time `Engine.connect()` is called? What happens when `Connection.close()` is called?

Comment: Hi, I believe that the pattern of manually creating connections against the Engine object is more common when using the [SQLAlchemy Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/index.html). A very common use-case with web apps is to use the [SQLAlchemy ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/index.html) and Session objects that are bound to an Engine instance. Are you specifically wanting to use the core for your work?

Comment: "Does the connection pool maintain a series of open connections to the database, and then hand a connection off whenever Engine.connect() is called?" Yes, except... "Or, does the pool establish a new connection every time Engine.connect() is called?" yes, if using [`NullPool`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool). "What happens when Connection.close() is called" depends on the pool in use. Source: [Connection Pooling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#module-sqlalchemy.pool)